# How to write to a BLE characteristic fast in an iOS app

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to transfer some data (tens of KB) over BLE from iOS to a BLE peripheral device. I use writeValue methods as specified [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue). The preset connection interval of a peripheral is ~ 30ms. However, after a bunch of GATT writes from my iOS app, the peripheral only gets 1 or 2 writes per seconds, which is way much slower than the expected value. It seems iOS queues up the write in some way, and send it out with a much slower rate. Is there any way to increase the data rate?

Answer (score 0):

Check automatic connection update issued from your BLE device. This can happen and lower transmission rate can be set and this will slow down the transfer.